# Solve $x^{2^{\sqrt{2}}} = {\sqrt{2}}^{2^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to solve:

$$x^{2^{\sqrt{2}}} = {\sqrt{2}}^{2^x}$$ where $x \in R^{+}$?

We take log based on 2 on both sides, then

$2^{\sqrt{2}} \log_2 x = 2^x \log_2 {\sqrt{2}} = 2^{x-1}$ (thanks for the comment suggestion). How do I move forward?

Comment: It is easy to see that $\sqrt{2}$ is a solution.

Comment: ... and there is a second solution between $2$ and $4$

Comment: Your first line is wrong. Note that it should be $2^{\sqrt{2}}\log_2(x)=2^{x-1}$

Comment: As @Henry noted, you seek a root of $\log_2x=2^{x-5/2}$ in $(2,\,4)$ (the LHS is greater at $x=2$, the RHS at $x=4$). It probably requires numerical methods.

Comment: Wolfy says the second root is about x ≈ 3.13556453061975...

Comment: You can simplify as far as: $$x = 2^{2^{x-c}}, c = 1 + \sqrt2$$ But I'm not sure if you can get a further analytical answer from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $x=\sqrt{s}$, we have:

$\sqrt{s}^{2^{\sqrt{2}}} = {\sqrt{2}}^{2^\sqrt{s}}$.

From a visual examination, the equation becomes an identity if $s=$2,

i.e.

$x=\sqrt{2}$.